# border style of href link button is not displayed in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, button, hyperlink

A border style of href link button is not displayed in Chrome browser. Here is the code of this issue:

```css
.link_button
{
 -webkit-appearance: button;
 -moz-appearance: button;
 appearance: button;
}

input[type=submit], .link_button
{
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 1px 6px;
 border: 10px solid red;
 color: #000000;  
 background-color: #DDDDDD;
}
```

```html
<p>
<a href="loaddata/" class="link_button">Go back for a new text</a>
</p>

<form action="loaddata/" method=get>
 <input type="submit" value="Go back for a new text">
</form>
```

Here is how Chrome browser (v.47) renders this code:

[image]

As seen there is no solid red borders around the href link button. The input button has these bordres.

At the same time, Firefox (v.42) renders the same code with solid red borders for the both types of buttons:

[image]

The question is why Chrome does not produce the borders in the case of a href link button? How it could be fixed?

Comment: `display: inline-block`

Comment: @StephenThomas - this does not help.

Answer (score 1):

The `appearance` property is designed to render elements as browser native elements. When using Google Chrome, they set `button` borders to `2px outset buttonface`. This cannot be overidden when using the `appearance` property.

However, to achieve a red border around `.link_button` use:

`box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px red;`

instead of `border: 10px solid red;`

Comment: Ok, thanks. However this works well only for a special case `bold-style: solid;`, but this will not work for general case, say if `bold-style: outset;`

Answer (score 1):

Please try this it works perfectly fine for you,

```
a
{
color: #000000; 
background-color: #DDDDDD; 
border: 10px solid red;
padding: 1px 6px;
}

input[type=submit]
{
text-decoration: none;
padding: 1px 6px;
border: 10px solid red;
color: #000000; 
background-color: #DDDDDD;
}
```

HTML code goes like this:

```
<body>
<p>
<a href="loaddata/" >Go back for a new text</a>
</p>

<form action="loaddata/" method=get>
<input type="submit" value="Go back for a new text">
</form>
</body>
```

Any further help needed please comment. Feedback much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that this exclusion of `appearance` block resolves the issue. However, this is also not a general solution because in the case of a default Chrome button design of the `border: 2px outset #DDDDDD`, the two buttons will be rendered differently.

Comment: yes you are right. But i have provided you the solution for the issue that you are facing currently. I'm gonna look for the suitable general solution.. But generally we developers go for the kick that we get instantly. haha

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

Instead of border use outline:

```
input[type=submit], .link_button
{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1px 6px;
    outline: 10px solid red;
    color: #000000;     
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
}
```

Comment: This question is about a border-style case. `outline` workaround does not fit me here.